# Do I need to convert stereo audio to mono for FFT?

Tags: audio, fft

I've found most of the other questions are asking *how* to convert stereo to mono, but I want to know do I *need* to convert my audio data from stereo to mono in order to do a FFT? If I don't, I know to do a FFT on both channels, but then how do I use them to find the fractal dimension of the audio? If I do, is it a good idea to just average the two values together?

Also I have millions of points and when you look at them you see what the audio signal looks like. If I have soo many points, why would I go about doing a FFT of only 1024 bytes?

This is the audio format I'm using: 
PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian

An example of what the buffer might get when I read off the stream: [41, 0, 68, 0]

If I am just averaging the two together this is how I do that:

```
amplitude1 = (double) (buffer[1] << 8 | buffer[0] & 0xFF) / 32767.0;
amplitude2 = (double) (buffer[3] << 8 | buffer[2] & 0xFF) / 32767.0;
double aveAmp = (amplitude2+amplitude1)/2;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "fractal dimension of the audio"?

Comment: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal_dimension
So after doing an FFT I would use some formula and it would find the power spectrum or something like that and I would get the fractal dimension from that.

Comment: It sounds like you are asking a few questions, and it's completely unclear what you are trying to do with fractal dimensions. Generally speaking, the correct answer to "do I need to convert from stereo to mono" is "it depends", so you might want to explain what you are doing the fft for. What you are trying to measure/accomplish?

Comment: For my senior research I'm determining the fractality of music that is generated by using different degrees of interpolation to see if there is a difference in fractality when compared. The math and MIDI music is already done and I can convert my MIDI data to real audio data easily. All over the place I see how to a FFT but NO ONE explains any of the prep work. Like if I have 30 million pts representing the waveform what do I need to do next in order to do the FFT? Divide the pts up according to what the sampling rate is and do a FFT on this subset? In regards to what I mean by fractal music.

Comment: Check out this link which shows how some researchers studied a TON of previous music and determined their fractality. This is what I'm shooting for to do with my music.
http://essayforth.com/read-file/musical-rhythm-spectra-from-bach-to-joplin-obey-a-1-daniel-levitin-pdf-1556048/
Back to my titled question. I'm convinced I just average the two together so I'm honestly asking this question just so I'm sure and to help anyone else who is wondering.

Answer (score 0):

The reality of sound isn't mono or stereo, it's a field in space. "Stereo" is a simple form of data compression that takes advantage of our lack of ears. Mono just takes it slightly further.

That said, "fractal dimensionality" isn't well-defined for audio. Taking stero, you could use the left channel as the X coordinate and the right channel as the Y coordinate, and you'd get a 2D path with an associated fractal dimensionality. This would be *entirely* unrelated to the fractal dimension of the equivalent "mono" one-dimensional interpretation of the same sound; the stereo fractal dimensionality would measure the true stereo content. (Truning mon in stereo by simply copying the signal would create a stero fractal dimensionality of 1.0, since L=R always and that's a line)

Comment: As much as I _really_ want to mark this as the answer my resulting data says otherwise. According to what my audio data says, I would get two different graphs if I plotted the left as the y and the right as the x and then vice-versa since I'm getting two different values for the both channels. Although I do agree I would get a completely different fractal dimension whether I took the stereo or the mono. I've come to accept just averaging the two together, but my current dilemma now is deciding whether to take the fourier transform of the entire song or do a 1024 sample of it at a time.

Comment: I have no clue why I would consider doing a sample compared to taking the ft of the entire song since I'll achieve a higher resolution. Plus I don't even understand how to combine all of the ffts together if I did do a sample.

Comment: @user2567273: If you get two graphs, you're doing it wrong. Don't plot x(t) and y(t); plot y(x) instead. That plot has its own fractal dimension, and it's a proper fractal dimension for stereo, but is it what you need? As for doing the FFT on the whole song, what would that even mean? Sure, you get a nice resolution, and there might be a peak at 437.31 Hz. Doesn't mean there's a sustained 437.21 note for the entire 3 minutes.

Comment: I meant you could plot y(x) twice and have two different looking graphs because you could have the right channel be x for the 1st one and have it be y for the second one. What I need is to find the fractal dimension of the songs I'm generating. If the right answer is using stereo and not mono, I'll use stereo. How does that affect my results of the fft or would I find the fractal dimension straight from this plot and how? Btw you are being a really big help to me so thanks!

Comment: @user2567273: That would just rotate the graph around the x=y diagonal and not affect the fractal dimension. But the main problem is that you still don't understand that _the_ fractal dimension of a song just does not exist.

Comment: You have to explain better than that because that is just not true.

Comment: @user2567273: Which bit? Flipping left/right=L/R being a flip around x=y ? Or the idea that _the_ fractal dimension exists, when there's at least a left signal, right signal, average signal, correlation, difference, and probably a few more?

Comment: What I'm saying is not true is the fractal dimension not existing. It can be estimated. I've looked at enough research to know it certainly exists.

Comment: @user2567273: Any sequence of numbers has a fractal dimension, the problem is that stereo can be represented in quite a few different ways.